# Uploading images with the help of arrays and fetch errors

Tags: php, mysql, image, file, upload

I use a script to upload a couple of images to a directory the code works great in case of just one picture will be uploaded.

If I want to upload two images or more and have an extension that is not accepted, the script will upload the one with the extension that is allowed to upload and shows the error message for the one who is not accepted, but the upload takes place. that's my first problem.

Second problem: In case of an error message I would like to display a message in which it is said, which of the images will be not allowed. I do not know how to fetch this one that has an unaccepted ending into a variable that I can echo to the error message.

*Here is the code I use:*

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){

    $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');

    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $array_value){

        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
        if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension) === false){
            $errors[] = 'its an unaccepted format in picture $variable_that_count';
            continue;
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[] = 'reached maxsize of 2MB per file in picture $variable_that_count';
        }

        if (count($errors) == 0){
            $path = "a/b/c/";
            $uploadfile = $path."/".basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$key]);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadfile)){
                echo "success.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it will be clear what I like to approach. If there is someone who could help out I really would appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Keep in mind that different to textboxes, you can't present the user the same form with the files in there (like with the text in there in textboxes). So probably it's not a bad idea to keep the successful upload in a session until you can decide further on.

Comment: this answer i do not understand... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you

Sample HTML

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br> <input type="file"
            name="image[]" size="40">
    </p>

    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br> <input type="file"
            name="image[]" size="40">
    </p>

    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br> <input type="file"
            name="image[]" size="40">
    </p>

    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br> <input type="file"
            name="image[]" size="40">
    </p>

    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br> <input type="file"
            name="image[]" size="40">
    </p>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
$allowedExtention = array (
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png',
        'bmp',
        'tiff',
        'gif' 
);
$errors = array ();
$output = array ();

if (! empty ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] )) {

    foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] as $key => $array_value ) {

        $fileName = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key];
        $fileSize = $_FILES ['image'] ['size'] [$key];
        $fileTemp = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] [$key];

        $fileExtention = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $fileExtention = strtolower ( $fileExtention );

        if (! in_array ( $fileExtention, $allowedExtention )) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = "File format $fileExtention not accepted for $fileName";
            continue;
        }

        if ($fileSize > 2097152) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = 'reached maxsize of 2MB per file in picture $variable_that_count';
continue ;
        }

        if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
            $path = "temp";
            $prifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExtention );

            var_dump ( $prifix );

            $uploadfile = $path . "/" . $fileName;
            $x = 0;
            while ( file_exists ( $uploadfile ) ) {
                $x ++;
                $uploadfile = "{$path}/{$prifix}-{$x}.{$fileExtention}";
            }

            if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $uploadfile )) {
                $fileName = basename ( $uploadfile );
                $output [$fileName] = "OK";
            } else {
                $output [$fileName] = "ERORR";
                $errors [$fileName] [] = "Can Move uploaded file to destination";
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump ( $errors );
var_dump ( $output );
```

Sample Output

```
string '79534296' (length=8)
string '89773706' (length=8)
array
  'download (1)' => 
    array
      0 => string 'File format  not accepted for download (1)' (length=42)
  'brief.docx' => 
    array
      0 => string 'File format docx not accepted for brief.docx' (length=44)
  '' => 
    array
      0 => string 'File format  not accepted for ' (length=30)
array
  '79534296-2.jpg' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  '89773706-2.jpg' => string 'OK' (length=2)
```

**Edit 1**

if all the files must be valid there are 2 ways to achieve that

A. Start By validating all files first ;

```
foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] as $key => $array_value ) {
    if(! in_array (pathinfo ($_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $allowedExtention ))
    {
        die("Die! Die! Die") ;
    }
}

foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] as $key => $array_value ) {
  // Upload Script here 
 }
```

B. Remove all files if an error is detected

```
foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] as $key => $array_value ) {
  // Upload Script here 
 }

// Remove All Files
if(count($errors) > 0)
{
    foreach ($output as $key => $value)
    {
        @unlink($path . "/" . $key);
    }

    die("Die! die! die!") ;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: okay, thanks a lot for coding. two little things i like to comment. first thing is that the problem still exists, when uploading one file that has an accepted ending and one that doesnt, the upload will be executed. second problem is, that i have an array now, that i wouldnt like to show. i would like to echo just the array [0] that contains 'File format docx not accepted for brief.docx' just this should be shown and not the whole array. how can i realise that? thank you very much.

Comment: I just testing ... it only accept files with valid ending ... can use see my `output` .. i uploaded `5 files` .. only `2` has == `OK`  .. also try to upload empty file ... can you see all is shown in the error output

Comment: hello, yes thats right but what i mean is, that when one file wont be accepted the upload of the file that will be accepted doesnt should be executed because once an user has post the form he is not allowed to add or change images. thats why i need to denie the upload in case of one file will be not accepted.

Comment: Oh .. now i understand what you want .... ` when one file fails don't allow any other file` i would update my code with the solution

Comment: exactly :) i'm sorry as a german sometimes it's hard to find the right words to express myself.

Comment: I just gave you 2 possible solution .. look .. choose the one that you like .. maybe i'll learn German form you someday

Comment: okay i choosed A it works great! thank you very much for helping so far. maybe you would be that friendly and can tell me how i can echo out the error messages in that way, that it wont be an array. i mean i would like to echo: File format docx not accepted for brief.docx // if i left var_dump it simply will show "array" and not the text. thanks a lot.

Comment: ahhh seems to be a small failure in A: i get error messages: Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/web775/html/build.php on line 152

Warning: Wrong parameter count for in_array() in /var/www/web775/html/build.php on line 152
Die!

Comment: Done ... replace `$_FILES ['image'] ['name'] with `$_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key]` .. that was the error .... :D

Comment: failure nr1 has gone. remains: Warning: Wrong parameter count for in_array() in /var/www/web775/html/build.php on line 152
Die!

Comment: replace ` if(! in_array (pathinfo ($_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ))` with ` if(! in_array (pathinfo ($_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ), $allowedExtention ))` ... should have tested it ..

Comment: now it works :) just some small failure is still given. if you upload two different file type it will display die. so the upload will be aborted but this scraps the main goal to inform an user which file is incorrect :)

Comment: thanks a lot for you professional help. i really appreciate. bye