# validating file upload server side - allow only images with php

Tags: php, security, validation, image-uploading

new guy here asking a question that what should be met with simple solutions.

I have tried a bunch of code. It seems I can get the file stream for getimagesize and get other things to work without crashing.

I'm dusting off an old project that needs to limit the files uploaded so that they are only image files and nothing evil.

This code always give me an error message no matter what

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['bf_file'][$key]['tmp_name']);  
if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/jpeg') {  
alert ("Sorry, we only accept GIF and JPEG images");  
exit;  
}
```

Here is the black list effort

```
$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".js", ".shtml", ".pl" ,".py"   
,".txt", ".doc");

foreach ($blacklist as $file)
{
if(preg_match("/$file\$/i", $_FILES['bf_file'][$key]['tmp_name']))
{
alert "ERROR: Uploading executable files Not Allowed\n";
exit();
}
}
```

Here is another getimagesize

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES[bf_file][$key][tmp_name]);
$fp = fopen($_FILES[bf_file][$key][tmp_name], "rb");
if ($size && $fp) {
header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
fpassthru($fp);
continue;
} else
// error
alert("Inappropriate file type");
```

On each of these I get the error message no matter if a file is uploaded or not.

I just need to place these controls somewhere in my file so that if the uploaded file passes the checks then everything just passes through as the uploader and everything else works like it should but without the benefit of these limiters and checks.

Also, the user should not be required to upload file. There are 3 fields, subject, body and file upload. Only subject and body are required to have data and that works right now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

James

Comment: What is the value of `$key`? Regardless of what it contains, due to some *premium* stupidity on the part some of the PHP authors a long time ago, you would need to reference `$_FILES['bf_file']['tmp_name'][$key]` instead of `$_FILES['bf_file'][$key]['tmp_name']`. Also please note that `getimagesize()` is the only sensible way to do this, I can't even begin to explain the things that are wrong with your blacklist approach in the small amount of space a comment gives me.

Comment: Here's one: Your preg_match is not multiline, so is vulnerable to whitespace attacks. One of a thousand reasons to use a whitelist, not a blacklist. Also you really need to be copying the pixel data from the image canvas, you are vulnerable to a malicous user uploading an image file that contains embedded server-side script, if you just save the file as-is.

Comment: @Cheekysoft, also, `index.php5` (it might exist) and `index.php.fr` ([content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html))

Answer (score 1):

Your script is all over the place example

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['bf_file'][$key]['tmp_name']);
```

To get temp name should be `$_FILES['bf_file']['tmp_name'][$key]` and also file size is already returned via `$_FILES['bf_file']['size'][$key]`

Why don't you take a look at  for details example on similar question

[multi image upload wrong quantity on file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170277/multi-image-upload-wrong-quantity-on-file-upload/10170975#10170975)

[Uploading images with the help of arrays and fetch errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093366/uploading-images-with-the-help-of-arrays-and-fetch-errors/10095087#10095087)

Comment: It should be obvious that I simply looked around and grabbed these codes from the web and threw them in my page. Talking about the position of the $key, this appears because there are multiple images that could be uploaded? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome .. click on the links there are details examples have done before ... and its very string froward .. you should not have issues customization it

Answer (score 1):

In first snippet. Well, `getimagesize()` actually returns MIME type (contrary to what Baba says), but you shouldn't depend on it. It's entirely possible to make file which at beginning looks like <del>PNG</del> GIF (any reason to block PNG?), but after header has `<?php dangerous_code(); ?>`. Also, I don't know what are you trying with `[$key]`. I don't know what it does and array looks like `$_FILES[$form_name][$file_field]` (for example `$_FILES['file_input']['tmp_size']`. There is no third field. Unless you are doing multiple files uploads, then look into what Baba said (it's very hacky feature). Next, PHP doesn't have `alert()` - you probably meant `echo`.

In second snippet, I see you're doing stuff incorrectly. Dot is meta character in regular expressions, but in this case it doesn't really matter. Blacklist approaches are flawed anyways as you don't know if your server doesn't support `.php5` extension for example. And even if it doesn't, somebody can abuse [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) in Apache by making file `hack.php.fr` (Apache thinks that `.fr` is language). Your approach is flawed - just give PNG files `.png` extension no matter what original extension was and so on.

In third example, you activate wrong variable - but also use barewords (you shouldn't, while I'm aware that you should have constants uppercase (so contrary to what PHP says, barewords aren't so dangerous if you have common sense), they are extremally slow, way slower than normal string and make a lot of errors if you have `E_NOTICE` (hint: you should)). Next, `continue` is not for `if` conditionals - it's for loop conditionals (it also works on `switch` (as `break`), but I guess it's just for consistency).

As for not having to upload files, it's easy. Just do conditional over `isset($_FILES['file_input_name'])`.

**tl;dr** - Learn PHP properly

Comment: `so contrary to what PHP says, barewords aren't so dangerous if you have common sense` - fair point, but they still clutter your error log with easily avoidable errors.

Answer (score 0):

By far the safest approach is to prevent your webserver from executing dynamic stuff in folders that user can upload to entirely. Then it doesn't matter what they upload.

An .htaccess file in your uploads directory containing `php_flag engine off` will prevent php. Other executable stuff should be disabled by default anyway, but you should definitely check.